# Is It Okay To Pray Witr Without Praying Taraweeh?

Tags: salat, ramadan, taraweeh, witr

Assalamualaikum Brothers and Sisters,
As an IGCSE Student at this time of the pandemic, I've been flooded with assignments from left to right, and have class at 10 am. I stay up late to read the Qur'an and pray, but I'm afraid that sometimes it may be too late for me to fall asleep and still be able to wake up in time for class. With this being mentioned, if I still want to offer my prayers, would I be allowed to offer just my Witr instead of both the Taraweeh and Witr?
JazakAllah Khair.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may. [Taraweeh is only a Sunnah Mu‘akkadah](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/16484), and Witr's status is high enough that the Hanafi madhab took it to be as wajib (obligatory). If you were to only offer one, then Witr would take precedence.