# Can Taraweeh b skipped few nights?

Tags: taraweeh, tahajjud

I offer taraweeh at home and read it from the Quran some surahs. Is it necessary that I offer taraweeh daily or can few nights be skipped during the month(due to tiredness or any reason other than monthly cycle)?

Also, Do we have to offer tahajjud prayers seperately if we are offering taraweeh? Please answer

JazakAllah

Comment: Taraweeh and tahajjud are not obligatory see for example [Is it okay to pray witr without praying taraweeh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/59872/is-it-okay-to-pray-witr-without-praying-taraweeh).

Comment: Its not obligatory but tiredness is barely an excuse for missing taraweeh if praying at home since very old men still go to the masjid and pray taraweeh for a few hours. However, if you are so tired to the extent you can't pray, then you can miss it.

Answer (score 1):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

`Is it necessary that I offer taraweeh daily or can few nights be skipped during the month(due to tiredness or any reason other than monthly cycle)?` (I take it that you are thinking it is obligatory and afraid of sinning by missing it)

**Taraweeh** prayer is not an obligatory prayer. **Taraweeh** according to Sunni jurisprudence is a recommended prayer offered in the nights of the month of Ramadan.

[Source - Is Tarawih Compulsory?](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/37742/is-tarawih-compulsory)

`Do we have to offer tahajjud prayers seperately?`

**Taraweeh** and **Tahajjud** are diffirent prayers.  So they are not prayed together.

**Taraweeh** is prayed in Shahri Ramadan, right after Isha Salah in Sunni traditions.

Whereas **Tahajjud** is prayed everyday during the whole year after midnight sleep, before Fajr starts.

Comment: Its not just recommended, its sunnah